# Google reCAPTCHA data-callback not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, recaptcha

I have built a email newsletter signup form which posts into mailchimp from my website. I have Google reCAPTCHA added to the form and have a data-callback to enable the submit button as it is initially disabled. This was working fine in all browsers last night and did tests with success & signed off on it..and went home. I got in this morning and found the subscribe button will not enable / data-callback does not work? Strange..

Callback

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptcha_callback" data-sitekey="xxxxx"></div>
```

Input button at bottom of form

```
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" disabled>
```

Scripts

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      function recaptcha_callback(){
        alert("callback working");
        $('.button').prop("disabled", false);
      }
    )};
</script>
```

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/44567543/317110

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Change your script to...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function recaptcha_callback(){
      alert("callback working");
      $('.button').prop("disabled", false);
    }
</script>
```

By placing your function inside the `document.ready` event, it is not in the global scope and therefore unreachable by the captcha control.

Comment: Is this a proper solution for recaptcha? I mean does the recaptcha_callback code only run when the recaptcha is successfully validated?

Comment: @Gsuz, the `data-callback="recaptcha_callback"` in the original question specifies the `recaptcha_callback` function as the callback.

Comment: @Gsuz Yes. Source: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param