# ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: myCallBack

Tags: jquery, recaptcha

I'm trying to use ReCAPTCHA where I am getting following error.

> ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: myCallBack.

How can I solve this issue?

```
var verifyCallback3 = function(response) {
    if(response!=null){
        $("#rss").show();
    }
};

var myCallBack = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
        'sitekey' : '6sssfffffffffAAPfEI_RkbAlUuw5FA4p-kiGy5Nea',
        'callback' : verifyCallback3,
        'theme' : 'light',
        'type':'image'
    });
};
```

Comment: Is this funtion `verifyCallback3 ` defined globally? Or inside other function?

Answer (score 43):

Make sure your callback function is being defined in the global scope. For some reason, in production my function was not in this namespace.

In addition to:

```
function myCallback() { ... }
```

Make sure you directly assign it into the global space:

```
window.myCallback = myCallback;
```

You should be able to test whether this is your problem, my typing the function name at the Javascript console and seeing if it's defined or not.

Comment: is there any way to do this within a es6 class module js file? there all my functions are defined without keyword 'function' and then initiated in constructor like `this.myFunction`. currently i just have `window.recaptchaCallback= recaptchaCallback` above my `function recaptchaCallback` definition which looks ugly sitting above my `export default class{}`

Answer (score 13):

The same thing happening with me.I have checked my code carefully, every thing is fine but captcha not shown and in console the message is "ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: myCallBack" but finally I found that my JavaScript code was is in page load function. I am just put out it from page load function and its working.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem.

Comment: That worked for me as well, i remove document.ready from script.

Answer (score 12):

In your recaptcha div, make sure not to use parenthesis in your data-callback.

Like so `data-callback="yourCallback"`, rather than `data-callback="yourCallback();"`

Comment: Is there still a way to pass a variable with it? It would be handy to pass in on which  form this was used

Comment: how can I have this callback function in global scope if I'm using es6 class modules?

Answer (score 12):

You have to put your script function:

```
<script> function registerFormCheck()</script>
```

Before the google script something like this:

```
/* First */    <script> function registerFormCheck(){} </script>
/* Second */   <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

This worked for me...

Answer (score 2):

As reference to the John Lehmann's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50292803/8483576), for **React** users, in order to make your callback function visible make it global.

You can achieve this by using `useEffect()` or `componentDidMount()` lifecycle methods.

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.verifyCaptcha = verifyCaptcha;
})
```

This way, when component that contains reCAPTCHA box loads, it will also make your callback function global.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely an error somewhere in the function or somewhere in your javascript causing the function to not become registered, for me it was a missing comma. From what you have, I'm guessing its related to 'html_element' or a widgetID not being assigned. Try:

```
var myCallBack = function() {
    var widgetID;
    widgetID = grecaptcha.render(document.getElementById('html_element'), {
        'sitekey' : '6sssfffffffffAAPfEI_RkbAlUuw5FA4p-kiGy5Nea',
        'callback' : verifyCallback3,
        'theme' : 'light',
        'type':'image'
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For me working this solution:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of the code samples in [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/loading#loading_recaptcha_asynchronously), they include this script tag without a closing tag:

```
<script async src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js">
```

Adding the closing tag fixed the problem for me:

```
<script async src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing:

Changing this:

```
var verifyCallback3 = function(response) {
   if(response!=null){
       $("#rss").show();
   }
};
```

To This:

```
function verifyCallback3(response) {
   if(response!=null){
       $("#rss").show();
   }
};
```

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issues and solved them by deactivating caching plugins. This issue often occurs in WordPress sites due to caching plugins. Deactivate the caching plugins and check.