# How to auto-click submit button as soon as reCaptcha solved in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, recaptcha

I have a chrome extension for particular page.

The submit button should be auto-clicked as soon as reCaptcha solved.

I tried like below, but not work.

```
function myCallBack() {
  var submit = document.getElementId("submit_btn");
  if (submit) {
    submit.click();
    console.log("submit clicked");
  }
}

$("div.g-recaptcha").attr("data-callback", "myCallBack");
```

I get console log like below:

```
ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: myCallBack
```

How to solve this problem? Help me please.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @AnuragR you mean reCaptcha version? I think it is reCaptcha v2.

Comment: Found some similar questions. [recaptcha-couldnt-find-user-provided-function-mycallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567543/recaptcha-couldnt-find-user-provided-function-mycallback)

[google-recaptcha-data-callback-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614606/google-recaptcha-data-callback-not-working)

Comment: I haven't got source code of the web page. should be solved with only extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. this will work on all sites when a captcha is clicked.
and in order to run this on any site. use "[Custom Javascript For Websites 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/ddbjnfjiigjmcpcpkmhogomapikjbjdk)" Extention for chrome. Change 'button[type="submit"]' to the button reference that needs to be clicked after.

```
let captcha_passed = setInterval(function(){
    if(typeof grecaptcha !== "undefined"){
        let gr = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        if(gr !== ""){
            clearInterval(captcha_passed);
            $('input.btn[name="captcha"]').click();
            $('button[type="submit"]').click();
        }
    }

}, 500);
```